# simulating the movement of droplet in a microfluidic device using matlab

Tags: matlab, simulation, fluid-dynamics

I would like to know, how to simulate droplet movement in a microfluidic device using matlab.

I'll try to narrow it down as much as I can, It's a situation where a water droplet is moving in a stream of oil, It's a potential flow(Inviscid, Incompressible and Irrotational), on the basis of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1008/1008.1155.pdf) I have managed to arrive at their equation (1) (page 3) for $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ and I wish to show the movement of the droplets in matlab in some kind of movie format

I have only basic knowledge of fluid dynamics, and I have never used matlab for more than just implementing mathematical methods, So I would appreciate any kind of help, if further details about the problem are required to help me understand what to do, please let me know

I posted in the physics.stackexchange website, and I was advised to post it here because It pertains to programming.

Comment: What extactly is your problem ? What part of your matlab code doesn't work ? You can check [this link](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html) to create a video. But if you don't even know what you need to program, it's going to be hard for us to help you.

Comment: @obchardon Thank you for the link!
I didn't know of such a function, so that was pretty much my question. (I was assuming I had to explicitly write a code to implement frame-by-frame movie in matlab).
but now that I know of such a function, I have another doubt..let's say I am tracking the movement of an object at different times, is it possible to take the position of the object at each 't' as a frame and use it in movie(M)?

Comment: of course: (for exemple a point in 3d) if you have a position (ie `pos(1) = [1 2 3]`) in space at t1 and another position (`pos(2) = [2 3 5]`) at t2. You can create a for loop (for i = 1:length(pos)) plot your position `plot(pos(i))` and get the frame with `F(i) = getframe;`. The process is similar for a sphere or a circle.

Comment: @obchardon Thank you so much, that really helped! :)

Comment: @obchardon could you tell me where I'm going wrong? I just randomly tried it like this, but it's only showing the final position, and not as a moving circle:


`figure

posx=[0 1 2];

posy=[2 3 4];

for i = 1:length(posx)

    plot(posx(i),posy(i),'o')
    F(i) = getframe;
end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first part of the question, how to show the droplet movement:

If example you can do:

```
X = rand(10,1)*10;
Y = rand(10,1)*10;
figure

for i = 1:length(X)
    plot(X(i),Y(i),'o')
    xlim([0,10]) %fix the x and y limit 
    ylim([0,10]) %fix the x and y limit 
    F(i) = getframe;
    drawnow
end

movie(F)
```

We have to fix the x-limit and y-limit otherwise your dot will always appear at the middle of the screen.

If you want to save the video (.avi for example):

```
X = rand(10,1)*10;
Y = rand(10,1)*10;

v = VideoWriter('test.avi'); %create a video in your current folder
open(v)

figure

for i = 1:length(X)
    plot(X(i),Y(i),'o')
    xlim([0,10])
    ylim([0,10])
    F(i) = getframe;
    writeVideo(v,F(i))
end

close(v)
```

And just for fun in 3d:

```
X = 1:100;
Y = 1:100;
Z = 1:100;

v = VideoWriter('test2.avi');
open(v)

[x,y,z] = sphere;

figure

for i = 1:length(X)
    surf(x+0.1*X(i),y+0.1*Y(i),z+0.1*Z(i));
    xlim([0,10])
    ylim([0,10])
    zlim([0,10])
    view(30,30)
    F(i) = getframe;
    writeVideo(v,F(i))
end



close(v)
```

But this method is quit slow because matlab have to render each frame.

Comment: i add an option to save the video

Comment: what if you want to delay the time between each frame? Can that be specified as some argument for the function?

Comment: you can write 2 times (or 3 or 4 time...) each frame... not really pure but it will works